# How to change the type of a variable of a super class in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass

I am trying to create a constructor in a subclass, but I want to change one of its "inherited" variables to something more appropriate for the subclass without changing the functionality of the superclass (specifically, I am trying to change the type of the variable from a `String` to an `Object` I made in another class). Problem is, I can't directly change or access the variable because it is private in the superclass and there is no setters for this variable.

Is there some other way to effectively override the superclass constructor so I can modify this "inherited" variable without editing the superclass? Or should I not be inheriting from the superclass in this case, even though all the other methods would remain mostly untouched?

Essentially, what I want to do is *something* like this:

```
//This should not be changed
public class Super
{
    private SomeArrayObject<String> o;
    private String a;
    private SomeObject b;

    public Super(String a, SomeObject b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        o = new SomeArrayObject<String>();
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        //Does something
    }
}

public class Sub
{
    private SomeArrayObject<ObjectFromOtherClass> o; //Notice the diff?

    public Sub(String a, SomeObject b)
    {
        super(a, b);
        o = new SomeArrayObject<ObjectFromAnotherClass> o;
    }
}
```

As a quick note, there is no "default constructor" in the superclass, so I can't just use `super()` and fill in the variables as needed.

Comment: “Inherited” private variable doesn’t make sense. Variables aren’t inherited. It would be better to add an example. However what you are trying to do seems impossible. You would have to modify the superclass (and risk breaking other things that extend from that superclass)

Comment: I assume that you intend for `Sub` to be declared `extends Super`? In that case you have *two* variables: `Sub.o` is in addition to `Super.o`, it doesn't override or replace it. The behavior that's happening is called shadowing.

Comment: @DanielPryden I do intend to extend `Super` (I forgot to include that in the example code). But what does "shadowing" entail? Does that allow the inherited methods in `Sub` to use the variable `Sub.o`, or will they only use `Super.o` unless I override the method?

Comment: You can't. However, properties are there to support behaviors. The idea of OOP is to use objects for their behaviors. Assuming you aren't using getters, `Superclass` must have some behavior that relies on `String`. But, you want the behavior of a subtype to rely on a different property. The the questions I have: what is the behavior in question, why does it rely on `String`, why would the subclass behavior require a different property, and are you sure you aren't violating the Liskov Subsitution principle?

Comment: @VinceEmigh  Ideally I'm trying to avoid changing the whole structure of `Super` (so that any class that already extends from it doesn't have to change), yet I want to deviate from `Super` in how `SomeArrayObject` is created. I made `ObjectFromAnotherClass` to act as a container that can handle specific information more efficiently than a plain old string, but `Super` (by default) uses strings because it handles very general information. I'm just wondering if it is a faulty design to rely on inheritance to fix the issue, or if I'm doing something wrong. Really, I'm trying to avoid copying code

Comment: @J.Adder with the new info I made an edit, tell if it works for you

Comment: @EJP that's very true, but the op was trying to do something else, he expressed wrong just it.

Answer (score 3):

I can see your problem. You can't modified it because is private right? and it's ok to be `private` variable, but in this such of cases, you can change the visibility of the variable to `protected`, so the subclass can see it and modify it.

Edit:

Seeing the new info, you have to do a few little changes more, add a generic, and makke the variable protected, an create a new generic class:

```
public class SuperClassGen<A>  {
    protected ArrayList<A> o;
    private String a;
    private int b;

    public SuperClassGen(String a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.o = new ArrayList<A>();
    }
}

public class SuperClass extends SuperClassGen<String> {
    public SuperClass(String a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClassGen<ObjectFromOtherClass> {
    public SubClass(String a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}
```

That will allow change the type from the subclass in the constructor, without

Comment: This wouldn't allow him to assign an `Object` to his `a` property, which is what the OP is requesting.

Comment: @VinceEmigh you're right, now with the new info I made an edit

Comment: This "sort of" resolves the issue: it requires that the `Super` 
class & constructor be changed syntactically (which I am trying to avoid) and requires that a new class be made to do so, yet maintains the same functionality as before (which is exactly what I need). It is a good solution, but I was hoping for something that does not modify the structure of `Super`. However, if it is impossible to keep `Super` the way it is to do what I want, I understand.